# How to run exe file and only after send it an argument

Tags: c#

I have client - server piece of code.
after the server running i create this to run the cliect:

```
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "message";
        p.StartInfo.FileName = @"AsynchronousClientSocket.exe";
        p.Start();
```

at this point the client connected to the server and now i want to send to the cliect exe an argument in order to reach the server and catch the server respond (int value)
How can i do this ?

Comment: Well what do you mean by "send"? What protocol is this server using? As written, this question is too vague to give it an answer.

Comment: The exe that is running could monitor a DB for a particular value? It depends on what is 'the server' as you have put, are you able to post some more code or further define the problem?

Comment: I am using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx to send the string fron the client to the server

Comment: The issue is not communication between the client and the server. It is between your program and the client (sending the argument, receiving the results). You have many IPC mechanisms available to you. Choose one.

Comment: Are you in control of `AsynchronousClientSocket.exe` as in can you edit the code and recompile it? You need to use some form of [IPC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to call functions and get results from those functions. Personally I recommend [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms735119%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for the [new user](http://ashepherd.co.uk/blog/?p=25)

Comment: Is it possible to use it with console application in the client side ? can i pass a string from one side to another and get respond ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at something which allows interprocess communication.

You could host a WCF service inside the exe, and then talk to that from the other code using a service ref...

The database idea that someone else mentioned is ok, but it means you'll have to be continually polling for a change in the underlying value, creating extra load on your database server and causing your DBAs to come after you with dogs...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/myargument";
p.StartInfo.FileName = "myprogram.exe";
p.Start();
```

Comment: So code your client so that it connects to the server first, then it sends the passed argument!  Do you know how to retrieve command line arguments in a C# WinForms application?...

Comment: I doesn't work, see my code..this code is after my client already connected and running

Comment: The client continue to run but not sending the message to the server